# Input by pressing enter once

Tags: c++, input

I'm a beginner so sorry if the question is confusing or badly expressed.
To cut it short, you need to give values for say, 3 variables and the input should be given in one line. For example you press 3 4 2 without pressing enter after each value but press it at the end. How would the code work?

Comment: `cin >> x >> y >> z;`

Comment: Default tokenising doesn't care if whitespace is blanks, tab, linefeed.

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so far (if any) with this question.

Comment: Sorry i haven't tried any because I have no idea what to try, but if it helps this is how I want to take input for three different variables https://i.imgur.com/2GjW53w.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I haven't logged in in  a while but I managed to answer it myself. My code is below and thank you for your answers and sorry for my lack of explanations.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char a[100];
string c;
int b[3], j=0, i;
cin.getline(a,100);
c=a;

for(i=0; i<3; i++)
b[i]=0;

for(i=0; i<c.length(); i++)
{
    if(isdigit(c[i]))
    {
        b[j]=b[j]+(c[i]-'0');
        //cout<<b;

        if(isdigit(c[i+1]))
        b[j]=b[j]*10;

        else
        j++;
    }


}

for(i=0; i<3; i++)
cout<<b[i]<<" ";



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is ambiguous.  Please consider using [RFC 2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) style to disambiguate.

If the 3 values MAY be given in one line:

```
int a,b,c; 
cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

If the 3 values MUST be given in one line:

```
#include <string>      // Edit:  don't forget these headers 
#include <sstream>     //            after those that you already include
...
string s; 
getline(cin,s);       // input one line 
istringstream sst(s);  // then parse that line
int a,b,c; 
sst >>a>>b>>c;
```

Comment: In the second example, you should use `istringstream` instead of `stringstream`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Indeed, since I only extract, I could   Thanks for pointing out :-)

Comment: why does it output -- [Error] variable 'std::istringstream sst' has initializer but incomplete type -- I'm using devc++ . This is the code https://i.imgur.com/0aW7yCT.png

Comment: @I_Burn It's because of missing includes.  I've edited the code to highlight the two includes that you need to insert after your iostream include.